# Regex - Strict validation for name in the local part of email address

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email

I have this regex for validating emails which filters 'John' from 'mycompany':

`/^([a-z0-9][a-z0-9.]*)?john([a-z0-9.]*[a-z0-9])?@mycompany\.com$/`

It's mostly working, just validates:

```
john@mycompany.com
asd.john@mycompany.com 
john.asd@mycompany.com
```

And not validating:

```
.john@mycompany.com
john.@mycompany.com
```

But it shouldn't allow:

```
asdjohn@mycompany.com  
johnasd@mycompany.com
```

How could i fix it?

Comment: This regex seems very brittle if you're not just using it for learning purposes. Why would you want to allow `john@mycompany.com` but not `asdjohn@mycompany.com`. The point of regex is to establish a pattern and match said pattern. For example, do you want to match `[first].[last]@[website]`? Do all people you are trying to match have the name John?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try put word boundary `\b` around the word `john`, which seems to work for your given cases:

```
var list = ['john@mycompany.com',
'asd.john@mycompany.com',
'john.asd@mycompany.com',
'.john@mycompany.com',
'john.@mycompany.com',
'asdjohn@mycompany.com',
'johnasd@mycompany.com']

var p = /^([a-z0-9][a-z0-9.]*)?\bjohn\b([a-z0-9.]*[a-z0-9])?@mycompany\.com$/
                             # ^^    ^^

list.map(email => ({[email]: p.test(email)}))
#[ { 'john@mycompany.com': true },
#  { 'asd.john@mycompany.com': true },
#  { 'john.asd@mycompany.com': true },
#  { '.john@mycompany.com': false },
#  { 'john.@mycompany.com': false },
#  { 'asdjohn@mycompany.com': false },
#  { 'johnasd@mycompany.com': false } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/.*?(john)[a-zA-Z0-9]*@mycompany\.com$/
```

Or the simplified version:

```
/.*?(john)\w*@mycompany\.com$/
```

You can test [here](https://regex101.com/r/3ytNaJ/1)